# Wordpress loggout link redirect to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using worpress and have added a loggout link in the nav:

```
echo '<a href="http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%252Flogin%252F&_wpnonce=a2b834fa87">Logout</a>';
```

I need it to redirect to the homepage instead of going to the login page.

If possible I would like to do this by modifying the link about.

I tried changing %252Flogin%252F to the url but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. But don't forget [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your homepage url.

```
echo '<a href="http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to='.urlencode($url_home).'&_wpnonce=a2b834fa87">Logout</a>';
```

Answer (score 3):

as the code indicates:

```
$redirect_to = !empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : 'wp-login.php?loggedout=true';
```

you can simply change your redirect_to param to 'index.php'.